# comparing the last values in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('xxxxxzzz'), 'b':[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1], 'c': [100, 101, 105, 110, 120, 125, 100, 150], 'd':[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]})
```

I group them:

```
groups = df.groupby(['a', 'd'])
```

I want to add another column to `df` that in each group shows the difference (in percentage) between the last value of `c` that its `b` is 0 and the last value that its `b` is 1.

For example in the first group I want to compare `c` of row 2 and row 1.

My desired `groups` looks like this:

```
('x', 0)
   a  b    c  d   result
0  x  0  100  0     3.96
1  x  0  101  0     3.96
2  x  1  105  0     3.96
('x', 1)
   a  b    c  d   result
3  x  0  110  1     9.09
4  x  1  120  1     9.09
('z', 0)
   a  b    c  d   result
5  z  0  125  0     20.0
6  z  1  100  0     20.0
7  z  1  150  0     20.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom function and use [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)

```
def func(s):
    l0 = s[s.b==0].tail(1).c.item()
    l1 = s[s.b==1].tail(1).c.item()
    s['result'] = (l1 - l0)/l0 * 100
    return s

df.groupby(['a','d']).apply(func)
```

Outputs

```
    a   b   c   d   result
0   x   0   100 0   3.960396
1   x   0   101 0   3.960396
2   x   1   105 0   3.960396
3   x   0   110 1   9.090909
4   x   1   120 1   9.090909
5   z   0   125 0   20.000000
6   z   1   100 0   20.000000
7   z   1   150 0   20.000000
```

If you need each groups separately, just use a list comprehension `[func(g) for n, g in df.groupby(['a','d'])]`

Answer (score 1):

We can do the following here:

1. Apply `.pct_change` method to calculate the percent change of each row
2. Conditionally fill the values of `result` column with `NaN`
3. After that apply `fillna` with `bfill` or `ffill`

```
# first we apply .pct_change to all rows
df['result'] = abs(round(df.groupby(['a', 'd', 'b']).c.pct_change() * 100, 2))

# after that we check if the value if b = 1 and the value of the row before = 0 and we fill in NaN if condition not true
df['result'] = np.where((df.b == 1) & (df.b.shift(1) == 0), df.result, np.NaN)
```

So we get:

```
   a  b    c  d  result
0  x  0  100  0     NaN
1  x  0  101  0     NaN
2  x  1  105  0    3.96
3  x  0  110  1     NaN
4  x  1  120  1    9.09
5  z  0  125  0     NaN
6  z  1  100  0   20.00
7  z  1  150  0     NaN
```

```
# then backfill and forwardfill NaN
df.result.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
df.result.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

print(df)
   a  b    c  d  result
0  x  0  100  0    3.96
1  x  0  101  0    3.96
2  x  1  105  0    3.96
3  x  0  110  1    9.09
4  x  1  120  1    9.09
5  z  0  125  0   20.00
6  z  1  100  0   20.00
7  z  1  150  0   20.00
```